# Authorization MVC3 ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

this is what I'm doing:
1: Custom Authorization which loads Home/NoAccess
2: the NoAccess method will redirect to the page the user came from.

What I want added to this, is that when the user goes through the NoAccess controller something is placed in the viewbag or w.e.. that I can use to show a small messagebox saying something like "You've got no access".

The problem I am having is that when I put something in my ViewBag it doesn't reach the View. 
Is there an easy way to redirect the user to his previous page when he doesn't pass authorization and show a alert popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewBag` contents is lost in the redirect.

Use `TempData` instead. The contents are stored until it's read.

Comment: I didn't really want to use anything with Sessions... even if it has another name.
Isn't their a more cleaner way to do this? I did get it to work wit TempData by the way.

Comment: @user1682627: Although its underlying implementation is `Session`, why are you reluctant to use `TempData`? This is the perfect use case for it. The payload is small and very short-lived.